# Is there a way to make git commit have -v as a default?

Tags: bash, shell, git

I have

```
git () { [ $1 = commit ] && command git commit -v "${@:2}" || command git "$@"; }
```

It makes `git commit` have `-v` as a default, otherwise pass on the params and do whatever the `git` command is.

But it seems like something that could be shortened?

fyi, I'm slimming down my `.bashrc` file.  Down to 28 (mostly readable still) lines so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to not repeat then `command git` part:

```
git () {
    if [ "$1" = commit ]; then set commit -v "${@:2}"; fi
    command git "$@"
}
```

Note that you should not use `$1` without double quotes. Always use double quotes around variable substitutions unless you know why you need to leave them out.

Don't use `&&` and `||` as shortcuts. It's cute, and it might save a few characters, but saving characters is pointless. Readability is important, and `if` states the intent of the code in a clearer way.

You may want to define an alias in your git configuration instead (but you can't shadow an existing command this way, you need to use a different name), with something like this in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
co = commit -v
```